# Почему не изменяется свойство контрола?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void HideAll()
{
   foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
      tb.Enabled = false;
}
```

У меня есть четыре `TextBox` и один `ComboBox`. В зависимости от выбранного элемента в `ComboBox`, нужно включить/выключить (Enabled) `TextBox`.

Самый, как я счел, оптимальный вариант - это сначала все отключить и потом включить нужные, но функция почему-то вообще не вызывается, даже вставлял `MessageBox` - всё тщетно.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем дело или другой оптимальный вариант, т.к в своем варианте я не учел, что на форме будут скрыты все `TextBox` (у меня их на самом деле не четыре, а больше)

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, e) => {
    comboBox2.Items.Clear();
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0) {
        HideAll();
        textBoxAn1.Enabled = true;
        textBoxAn2.Enabled = true;
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1) {
        HideAll();
        textBoxAn1.Enabled = true;
        textBoxAn2.Enabled = true;
        textBoxAn3.Enabled = true;
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2) {
        HideAll();
        textBoxAn1.Enabled = true;
        textBoxAn2.Enabled = true;
        textBoxAn3.Enabled = true;
        textBoxAn4.Enabled = true;
    }
    comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
};
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51865/discussion-on-question-by------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свойство `Controls` для элемента управления возвращает только те элементы, которые непосредственно в нем находятся. Для обхода всех элементов (включая вложенные) используйте рекурсивный вариант:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(this Control control)
    {
        var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

        return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl)).Concat(controls);
    }
```

В вашем случае это не нужно, т.к. достаточно просто указать для перебора группирующий элемент:

```
foreach (TextBox tb in groupBox1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
```